# Find error on PHP Mysql

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax

How I can i find if there is an error on this code? Here is my code. Thanks in Advance!

```
else if(isset($_POST['UPDATECSSGOLD']))
{

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE  css set STYLE_STATUS = 'allnull'");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE  css set STYLE_STATUS = 'selected' where STYLE_NAME='GOLD'");
$stmt->execute();

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I am using ajax to send the query here is my AJAX code

```
<script>
function UPDATECSSGOLD()
{
$.post('insert_home.php',{
UPDATECSSGOLD:'selected'}).done(function(data){
alert ('THEME SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED!');                      
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: start by executing???

Comment: The error in your code... .is what?

Comment: Do you have an actual error or do you want to keep track of potential errors?

Comment: i want to track the potential errors sir

Comment: the browser should alert THEME SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED! if the query is successful, but it doesnt, is there something wrong with the php mysql part?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

```
try
{
    //your code
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage(); //or some value to capture in javascript later
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from implementing exceptions which is a good practice, to debug SLQ code in PHP you should follow on of these options:

Option 1: Run the SQL code directly in MySQL workbench. When it works there, you simply change the way parameters are passed which is always the same processed. Most of the time when my SQL wouldn't work in PHP, I managed to solve it very easily when I tried pasting it in Workbench and testing it there.

Option 2: Ideally, you would move the SQL code in procedures. Apart from being much safer against SQL injection, this method makes your life much easier to debug as the SQL logic will be completely seperate from your PHP logic. After implementing the SQL in a procedure, all you would need to do in PHP would be:

```
$mysqli->prepare('CALL YourProcName()');
```

And you pass parameters you would do:

```
$mysqli->prepare('CALL YourProcNameWithParams(?, ?)');
```

Where the question marks are the individual parameters that your Procedure is waiting for.

EDIT:

From your question it looked like you wanted to check for any SQL syntax error inside PHP so this answer is not very relevant after you commented that you want to keep track of potential errors.